# Google Places API, Ratings with date and time

Tags: google-places-api

Google Places API allows me to get the ratings for a place like so:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=<>&key=<>

It then returns the overall rating for the place like so:

```
...       
"result" : {

          "vicinity" : "...",
           "rating" : 3.7,
           "user_ratings_total" : 49
    ...
```

Is it possible to get each rating with date time also? Not just the aggregated value.

Comment: Seems like it were not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Check out this Placeid:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJOWSLUlcJ9YgR5Uxn4sbjYGk&key=<>

Here's a sample.  Notice the "Time" tag:

```
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "overall"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Michaela O'Neal",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/105457747713750328544",
        "language" : "en",
        "rating" : 5,
        "text" : "Love to go here for breakfast! They have amazing croissants and there are definitely many choices to pick from! We always had a really nice server and if it's nice weather outside they have a cute patio. It might get a little too loud inside during weekends. ",
        "time" : 1401332428
     },
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "overall"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Myles Rothacker",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/115555770858439445523",
        "language" : "en",
        "rating" : 5,
        "text" : "I love the Eggs Benedict. Dollar the waiter is great.. I go in about 2 times a month have a few business meetings he is always at the top of his game. Timing when to refill, not interrupting and waiting until we are done to give me the check. This is a great place to have a morning meeting or a casual brunch. ",
        "time" : 1375492655
     }
```

Comment: But this you get only when someone makes a review, you don't get a timestamp if someone just rates it.